# Graphing quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

The function,
$f(x)=x^2-x-2$
gives me the below graph
[image: image 1]

But, in a text book for the same equation, they have given different graph.  Which one is correct?

Text book graph - (i tried with ms paint, could not get perfectly the curve)...the points are as below,

[image: Image 2]

Curve: $(-2,4),(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1),(2,4)$
Line: $(0,2),(1,3),(-1,1),(2,4),(-2,0)$

Comment: use Wolfram alpha to plot your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they both are different graphs.

First with parabola y = $\left(x - \frac12 \right)^2 - \frac94$

Second graph with parabola y = $x^2$

and line  y = x + 2.

Comment: @Kanwalijit Singh The given equation is, x^2-x-2=0, So which one should i have to draw?

Comment: First graph is correct.

Comment: Let me explain you one point in graph is (-1,0). As we put x=-1 we get y=0. Other point is (2,0) as we put x=2 we get y=0. So first graph.

Comment: Clear or have some doubt.

Comment: Thanks.  Are the x values are picked randomly

Comment: Yes you can but try to avoid fraction values.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a plot of the curve $y=x^2-x-2$, with the intent to show the roots.

The second is a plot of the parabola $y=x^2$ and the straight line $y=x+2$, with the intent to show the intersections.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say, both are correct?

Comment: @raman What do you mean by "correct" ?

Comment: can i write any one of the above graph in exam?

Comment: @Raman: yes, provided you understand what they mean (which I doubt a little).